# installing tables and prevention from duplicated input for 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, create-table

look at my code, there is something wrong when I install my tables, I dont know what to do with it. And also Im trying to prevent from duplicated input for `meno` and `priezvisko` columns, when inserted in the form together with values that are already in database.

```
    / vytvorenie tabulky TRIEDA

  $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trieda(
            id_triedy INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
            nazov CHAR(5),
            PRIMARY KEY (id_triedy),
            UNIQUE KEY (nazov))";

 // vytvorenie tabulky STUDENT


 $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(
                    id_student INT (5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    id_triedy INT (5) NOT NULL,
                    meno CHAR (15),
                    priezvisko CHAR (20),
                    PRIMARY KEY (`meno`, `priezvisko`),
                    KEY (id_student))";


  // spustenie dopytu
  if (mysqli_query($prip,$sql))
  {
    echo "Tabuľka vytvorená";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<a href='./index.php'><strong>Späť</strong></a>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Chyba vytvorenia tabuľky: " . mysqli_error($prip);
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<a href='./index.php'><strong>Späť</strong></a>";
  }
```

EDIT: (gives error: Chyba vytvorenia tabuľky: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student( id_student INT (5) NOT ' at line 7)

```
// vytvorenie tabuliek do DB

  $sql= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trieda(
            id_triedy INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
            nazov CHAR(5),
            PRIMARY KEY (id_triedy),
            UNIQUE KEY (nazov));

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(
                    id_student INT (5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    id_triedy INT (5) NOT NULL,
                    meno CHAR (15),
                    priezvisko CHAR (20),
                    PRIMARY KEY (`meno`, `priezvisko`),
                    KEY (id_student))";



  // spustenie dopytu
  if (mysqli_query($prip,$sql))
  {
    echo "Tabuľka vytvorená";
....
```

EDIT2:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


    //meno a priezvisko
    $student = $_POST['meno'];
    $priezvisko = $_POST['priezvisko'];
    $id_trieda = $_GET['id_triedy'];



    //connect to the database
    include 'config.php';

    //insert results from the form input

$row = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE meno='{$student}' AND priezvisko='{$priezvisko}'");

if($row){
  echo 'Duplicate!';
}else {
  mysqli_query("INSERT INTO student (meno, priezvisko, id_triedy) VALUES( '{$student}', '{$priezvisko}', {$id_trieda} )");   
}
/*  $add = "<table align='center'>
            <tr>
                <td> Študent bol úspešne pridaný do triedy. </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href='./trieda.php?id_triedy=".$_GET['id_triedy']."'><strong>Späť</strong></a></td>
            </tr>
            </table>";
    $not_add = "<table align='center'>
            <tr>
                <td> Študent s týmto menom a priezviskom už je v tejto triede. </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href='./trieda.php?id_triedy=".$_GET['id_triedy']."'><strong>Späť</strong></a></td>
            </tr>
            </table>";
*/  



mysqli_close($prip);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that you are overwriting `$sql`.

```
$sql= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trieda(
            id_triedy INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
            nazov CHAR(5),
            PRIMARY KEY (id_triedy),
            UNIQUE KEY (nazov));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(
                    id_student INT (5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    id_triedy INT (5) NOT NULL,
                    meno CHAR (15),
                    priezvisko CHAR (20),
                    PRIMARY KEY (`meno`, `priezvisko`),
                    KEY (id_student))"
```

Link to [mysqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7195c).

**EDIT:**
Like you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009605/mysql-syntax-error-on-table-creation), your problem is that `mysql_query()` on `PHP` doesn't accept many queries in same string, so you must send it separately.

```
$sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trieda(
                id_triedy INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                nazov CHAR(5),
                PRIMARY KEY (id_triedy),
                UNIQUE KEY (nazov));"
$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(
                    id_student INT (5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    id_triedy INT (5) NOT NULL,
                    meno CHAR (15),
                    priezvisko CHAR (20),
                    PRIMARY KEY (`meno`, `priezvisko`),
                    KEY (id_student));"
```

Comment: it might be a problem because it always creates only the student table...but I also tried to rename it and edit the if condition but gives me en error...any ideas?

Comment: What error you get? (I edited the answer with your `sql` should do for the moment

Comment: check my edit, I had to add a semicolon on the end of your code because I got error for my if condition...and now I get this error..

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? I've tried on sqlfiddle and it works with all MySQL versions installed on it :/

Comment: okay carexcer, but how will the if condition look like with two strings?

Answer (score 1):

For prevent duplicate set composite unique key on fields `meno` and `priezvisko` ( you did it: "PRIMARY KEY (`meno`, `priezvisko`)"). Now do inserting like `INSERT IGNORE INTO...`. See more http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html.

**EDIT**

*Classic way*

```
try{

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE meno="'.$student.'" AND priezvisko="'.$priezvisko.'"';
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $sql); // escaping string 
$row = mysqli_query($link,$sql); // doing select - check on duplicate

if (mysqli_num_rows($row)){ // if return > 0 is means duplicate 
   echo 'Duplicate!';
}else{ 
     // not duplicate
     echo 'Inserting';
     mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO student (meno, priezvisko, id_triedy) VALUES( '{$student}', '{$priezvisko}', '{$id_trieda}') "); // inserting
 }

} catch (Exception $e){
      echo  $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: okay but if I use INSERT IGNORE, it doesnt give me error, it just doesnt add the value but it shows that the value was inserted ...

Comment: u need check state : duplicate or not ? "it just doesnt add the value" - yes. show code where you do inserting

Comment: $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO student (meno, priezvisko, id_triedy) VALUES( '{$student}', '{$priezvisko}', {$id_trieda} )";

Comment: @feri updated. Do u sure that is duplicate exists row for params    `$student = $_POST['meno'];` and `$priezvisko = $_POST['priezvisko'];`?

Comment: checking but still errors... your code is not written properly,youre missing ) { ... try to check it again please

Comment: @feri  I write here,without highlights - may be errors. see now.

Comment: what about the { after else?? im getting error because of that...cause i have a condition for submitting a form on very top of my code...

Comment: I can, but go to my project website and try to add a name into the classroom..see errors www.bekescars.sk/projekt/

Comment: @feri i tried `2.B` - exists. All right. I added `417` - doesnt exists. Added. All right . Look at http://www.bekescars.sk/projekt/index.php. You cann`t add duplicate

Comment: but go into the classroom and add a student, it says duplicate every time

Comment: yes i did..it shows nothing after submiting new student..doesnt even add a student..

Comment: Do you see new rows in DB ?

Comment: @feri update now. I think new rows doest insert. I want see on server $_POST and $_GET and exception

Comment: @feri i dont understand: new row doesnt insert?

Comment: i found a problem, sometimes when i want to add a name with same name, it says duplicate and sometimes it says duplicate when i use same last name....what the hack? and sometimes it works without problems..

Comment: actually, the problem is that if user with name LOL LOLEC exists in one classroom, I cant add a student with same name into other classroom and I should! cause there can be more students with same name...?

Comment: @feri add compare with classroom_id ... I  helped with prevent insert duplicate in classroom...  Sorry, I havent more  time for help.